# How to force repoquery to resolve to the latest available release of a package?

Tags: centos, yum, rpm

I am attempting to download RPM dependencies using `repoquery` and `yumdownloader`, but I am getting inconsistent results. How can I force `repoquery` to always return the latest compatible package that is available in a repository?

I get inconsistent results depending on how I call `repoquery`:

```
$ repoquery --whatprovides systemd-python
systemd-python-0:208-20.el7_1.6.x86_64
systemd-python-0:208-20.el7.x86_64
systemd-python-0:208-20.el7_1.3.x86_64
systemd-python-0:208-20.el7_1.2.x86_64
systemd-python-0:208-20.el7_1.5.x86_64
$ repoquery --resolve systemd-python
systemd-python-0:208-20.el7_1.6.x86_64
$ repoquery --requires salt
...
systemd-python
...
$ repoquery --requires --resolve salt
...
systemd-python-0:208-20.el7_1.5.x86_64
...
```

It resolves to release `20.el7_1.6` when queried alone but resolves to release `20.el7_1.5` when it's found as a dependency.

It get even more perplexing when, after I update my system to `systemd-python` release `20.el7_1.6`, `repoquery` begins to resolve the dependency to the oldest release:

```
$ repoquery --requires --resolve salt
...
systemd-python-0:208-20.el7.x86_64
...
```

Why am I getting these inconsistent results? How can I force `repoquery` to resolve the latest package releases from the repository, regardless of what is installed on the local system?

Answer (score 5):

For old yum repoquery in your question you probably could not.

For new one (which is DNF plugin) you can: `dnf repoquery --latest-limit 1`